# Ensure sequential running of tasks (Apache Airflow)

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Under a sequential executor, I have a DAG file where I specify three tasks that are needed to be run sequentially (t1-->t2-->t3):

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 6, 14, 23 , 20),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    }

dag = DAG('test_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *")

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='form_dataset',
    bash_command='python 1.py',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='form_features',
    bash_command='python 2.py',
    depends_on_past=True,
    dag=dag)

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='train',
    bash_command='python 3.py',
    depends_on_past=True,
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t2)
t4.set_upstream(t3)
```

I assume the sequential behavior t1-->t2-->t3 to be a default one, thought it's not the case in my situation (the order is pretty much random, e.g. t1-->t2-->t2-->t1-->t3). What kind of argument I am missing that would correct the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the statement

```
t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

at the end of the file. More details for this are on the following link:
https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#bitshift-composition

For completeness, you can also do it by using set_upstream() or set_downstream() methods for tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I actually have it (sorry I didn't put it in the code). I guess the problem is that the total amount of running time for all three tasks is greater that the schedule interval. I would like to set priority on the execution of the all tasks within a DAG over running a new DAG, but didn't find a related attribute so far.

Comment: Does the execution of every DAG run depend on the successful completion of previous run? In that case, you can look into the behavior of the parameter depends_on_true. There is another option to assign each task to a pool and limiting the size of that pool to 1. Or maybe I am misunderstanding your use case? In general, the dag tasks should be as much independent of other runs as possible.

Comment: In airflow.cfg there is a setting max_active_runs_per_dag. Setting this to 1 should also prevent the same dag from starting again before the previous one finishes.

Comment: Thank you very much - 'max_active_runs_per_dag' is just what needed! Good luck with your study at ETH (graduated there a short time ago)